# How to get a list of nodes 'inorder' with python igraph

Tags: python, igraph

**My Code:**

```
from igraph import Graph, plot

g = Graph(directed=True)

g.add_vertices("A", attributes=dict(operation="-"))

g.add_vertices("B", attributes=dict(operation="*"))
g.add_vertices("C", attributes=dict(operation=4))
g.add_vertices("D", attributes=dict(operation=8))

g.add_vertices("E", attributes=dict(operation="/"))
g.add_vertices("F", attributes=dict(operation=10))
g.add_vertices("G", attributes=dict(operation=2))

g.add_edges((("A", "B"), ("A", "E")))
g.add_edges((("B", "C"), ("B", "D")))
g.add_edges((("E", "F"), ("E", "G")))

io = [v['operation'] for v in g.vs]
print(*io)
```

**Yields**:

```
- * 4 8 / 10 2
```

**I would like**:

```
4 * 8 - 10 / 2
```

**I've searched the manual here:**
[docs](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#vs)

(Here is an image of the plotted graph, to help visualize the question.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest augmenting the edges with an explicit left- or right hand side annotation.

```py
g.add_edges([("A", "B"), ("A", "E")], attributes={"side": ["L", "R"]})
```

Starting from the root node, you can then recursively construct its left and right hand strings and concatenate them as follows (untested).

```py
def ordered(g, node) -> str:
    edges = g.adjacent(node) # uses mode=OUT by default
    if len(edges) == 2:
        lhs = next(edge.target_vertex for edge in edges if edge["side"] == "L")
        rhs = next(edge.target_vertex for edge in edges if edge["side"] == "R")
        return ordered(g, lhs) + node["operation"] + ordered(g, rhs)
    else:
        return node['operation']
```